# Export variable in PHP exec

Tags: php, variables, command-line-interface

I'm trying to do the following: inside `script.php`:

```php
\exec('export FOO=BAR');
```

Now if I run `script.php` in CLI, then run `echo $FOO`, `$FOO` doesn't appear to be set.

Any ideas how can I properly "export" a CLI variable from PHP's  `\exec()`?

Comment: Is https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php what you're looking for?

Comment: The execution within PHP is active only for the scope of the script execution, not outside. It is not fully clear if you want to import or expot an ENV var, because your scenario is about exporting.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I think he rather looking for `putenv()`.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I'm tried, doesn't seem to work also

Comment: @DanielW. Yeah I want to set `FOO` as environment var in CLI

Comment: @IMB what is your real use case? In modern software design, you usually don't change the environment from within the application. If you want a generator for specific vars, you should let PHP write a `.env` file and reimport that in the final destination.

Comment: @DanielW. It's for dev environment only. I'm tired of doing `export FOO=BAR` (where `BAR` is a random long string) every time I start a docker container.

Comment: @DanielW. Basically, I'm just creating a shortcut script because I type `export FOO=BAR` in CLI way too often everyday while in dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do that. Don't change environment from within application. Start your container with the string instead:

In `./start-docker-development-container.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export RANDOM_STRING=`pwgen -Bs1 12`
docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans
```

In `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    your_service:
        environment:
            RANDOM_STRING: ${RANDOM_STRING}
```

Comment: I can see this working but is there really no way for my initial approach to work, basically no way to "export" a var from PHP to a CLI env?

Comment: @IMB you could start your (development) PHP script using `<?php $_ENV['RANDOM_STRING'] = rand();`, but it does not make sense to first export from PHP and then reimport to PHP. If you need to, set it in docker-compose or your start dev script.

Comment: I'm not really setting an `$_ENV` in PHP, I literally just need to run `export FOO=longSecretString` inside a PHP shortcut script.

Comment: @IMB ENV vars set in PHP are only set until the end of the script. You can export it by letting PHP write a file and then use `source <file>` in bash. There is no way for PHP to manipulate ENV vars outside of the runtime scope. It's even easier to make this in bash like in the script shown above.

Comment: If that's the case then I think all I need is a bash script with `#!/bin/bash` `export FOO=BAR` `docker start mycontainer`. I don't think I really need to modify the `docker-compose.yml` file right?

Comment: @IMB `docker start` does not allow environment variables. `docker run` allows `-e <variable>` but best option is to use `docker-compose.yml` and just add the variables.

Comment: @IMB The very best solution would be to have an environment specific .env file with the variables already in, but talking about your env loading in the application is a little too long of a talk for comments.